# Finding density function of $\operatorname{E}[X\mid Y]$ and $\operatorname{E}[Y\mid X]$

Tags: conditional-expectation, density-function, expected-value

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$ 
Finding density function of $\E[X\mid Y]$ and $\E[Y\mid X]$, where $\E[X\mid Y]=Y/2$, $\E[Y\mid X]=X+1,$ $f(x,y)=e^{-y}$, and $0 \leq x \leq y$.

I am unsure on how to find the density of an expected value, could anyone please help me with the formula or method to use to find it?

Comment: Or $\mathsf{E}[Y\mid X=x]=x+1$, and $\mathsf{E}[X\mid Y=y]=y/2$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry I didn't notice while typing, edited

Comment: Then is should be clear that you need to find the densities of $X+1$ and $Y/2$ given the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$...

Comment: @d.k.o. Could I use the transformation method? Let $W=X+1$. $f(W)=f(x) \lvert{\frac{dX}{dW}}\rvert=e^{-x}(1)=e^{-x}$ And let $T=Y/2$. $f(T)=f(y) \lvert{\frac{dY}{dT}}\rvert=ye^{-y}(2)=2ye^{-y}$

Comment: $X+1\ge 1$. $f(T)$ is ok.

Comment: Is the question really to find the joint density of $(Y/2,X+1)$?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$
$$
\iint\limits_{\{\,(x,y)\,:\, 0\,\le\,x\,\le\,y\,\}} e^{-y} \, d(x,y) = \int_0^\infty \left( \int_x^\infty e^{-y} \, dy \right) \, dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \, dx = 1
$$
and thus this is indeed a probability density.

The conditional density of $y$ given the event $X=x$ is $\big( \text{constant}\cdot e^{-y} \big)$ for $y\ge x.$ Since
$$
\int_x^\infty e^{-y}\,dy = e^{-x},
$$
the "constant" must be $1/e^{-x} = e^x.$ Thus the density is $e^x e^{-y} = e^{x-y} \text{ for } y\ge x.$ The conditional expect value is therefore
$$
\E(Y\mid X=x) = \int_x^\infty e^{x-y} \, dy = x+1,
$$
so we can say
$$
\E(Y\mid X) = X+1.
$$
For the conditional density of $X$ given $Y=y,$ note that the joint density does not depend on $x$ beyond the fact that $0\le x\le y,$ so the density is constant on the interval from $0$ to $y;$ in other words, given $Y=y,$ the conditional distribution of $X$ is the uniform distribution on that interval.